# Planning Scene/C++ API Tutorial missing part

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, as I was reading this tutorial (sorry but I don't have enough karma to post a real link):

```
xxxx://docs.ros.org/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/planning_scene_tutorial.html
```

I saw that the right way to maintain current planning scene is to use the *PlanningSceneMonitor*:

> The PlanningSceneMonitor is the
> recommended method to create and
> maintain the current planning scene
> (and is discussed in detail in the
> next tutorial)

But I haven't find in any of the other Moveit tutorials any reference to that class.
Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?
Tx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186137/planning-scene/c++-api-tutorial-missing-part/) by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2014-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the answer to this question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/157716/obstacles-management-in-moveit/

That contains code snippets too. I hope it helps. That tutorial, according to the answer, was never written.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0